# Remove value of EditText with TextWatcher when the currency is equals to 0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textwatcher

I'm trying to clean the `EditText` when the value is equals to `R$0,00`.

What I've tried to do is clear the the text using `edittext.clear();` but without success, and using `valor.removeTextChangedListener(new Ferramentas.EditValor(valor));` also didn't change a thing, so how can I do that?

```
public static class EditValor implements TextWatcher {

        private String current = "";
        private EditText valor;


        public EditValor(EditText text){
            this.valor = text;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!s.toString().equals(current)) {

                current = valorMoeda(s.toString());
                valor.setText(valorMoeda(s.toString()));
                valor.setSelection(valorMoeda(s.toString()).length());
            }

        }
    }
```

ValorMoeda:

```
public static String valorMoeda(String s) {


        String replaceable = String.format("[%s,.\\s]", NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().getCurrency().getSymbol());
        String cleanString = s.replaceAll(replaceable, "");

        double parsed;
        try {
            parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            parsed = 0.00;
        }
        String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format((parsed / 100));


        return formatted;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear your text in `afterTextChanged()` method, e.g:

```
 yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

          if("R$0,00".equals(s.toString())){
             yourEditText.setText(""); // or yourEditText.getText().clear();
          }

        }

});
```

**UPDATE**:

Try this code:

```
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

         String newString = s.toString();

         if (newString.length>0 && !newString.equals(current)) {

            String newFormattedValue = valorMoeda(s.toString());

            if("R$0,00".equals(newFormattedValue)){
               valor.setText("");
            } else {
               current = newFormattedValue;
               valor.setText(newFormattedValue);
               valor.setSelection(newFormattedValue.length());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!s.toString().equals(current)) {

                current = valorMoeda(s.toString());
                valor.setText(valorMoeda(s.toString()));
                valor.setSelection(valorMoeda(s.toString()).length());
            }

            if("R$0,00".equals(s.toString())){
                valor.setText(""); // or yourEditText.getText().clear();
            }

        }`  when the value is equals to 0 thea keyboard freezes

Comment: Keep `if("R$0,00".equals(s.toString())){ valor.setText(""); }` inside `afterTextChanged()` and remove the rest of code, and see if your keyboard still freez.